AKS - Azure function installing unwanted ExtensionBundle
We recently moved our Azure Function into AKS. In twistlock report vulnerability was raised for microsoft.data.sqlclient, which we upgraded to 5.2. But still after deployment twistlock is reporting vulnerabiltity with 3.0.0 version.
After some digging we found that it is installed through Azure Function Bundle Extensions.

Is there any way I can prevent installing this unwanted extensions?

You can make use of existing default Azure Function docker image to run in your AKS:-
kubectl run my-first-pod --image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:latest
kubectl expose pod myfunctionappaks --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --name=func-aks-service
kubectl describe service func-aks-service
kubectl get svc

Use the external service IP to access your Function app from AKS.
Output:-



You can inspect your current Dockerfile and remove the unwanted package like below:-
Dockerfile:-
# Use the Azure Functions .NET base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:latest AS base

WORKDIR /app

COPY YourFunctionApp.csproj ./

# Remove unwanted packages from the .csproj file
RUN sed -i '/<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="3.0.0" \/>/d' YourFunctionApp.csproj && \
    sed -i '/<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.3" \/>/d' YourFunctionApp.csproj

RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 80

# Define the command to run your function app when the container starts
CMD ["dotnet", "YourFunctionApp.dll"]

Check if any existing package has dependency on Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Refer this Azure Functions on Kubernetes with KEDA | Microsoft Learn to deploy your Azure Functions on AKS with KEDA.
Also, Modify your Azure DevOps or CI/CD pipeline or Azure Functions deployment to exclude the package from getting built while deployment.

Using latest image of azure function does resolve this issue but then we are facing other issues related to other third party libraries.

Try adding thier package or war in your docker image?
